# Solr : Rank matches with beginning of string higher than matches within the string

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

Is there any way in Solr which can rank matches with beginning of string higher than matches within the string?

For eg:- I have a text field in solr and on searching for "xpo" on this field should return results where xpo matches at beginning higher than the ons's where xpo comes somewhere in the middle, like below

```
xpo test 
xpo test1
export test
test export
```

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use copy field to do that.

There are at least two options:

1. You can copy the first word in the string to another field, and thus get a higher ranks (you need to search on both fields).
2. You can create copy the entire string, but have multiple copies of words in the beginning (for example, 3 copies of the first word, 2 copies of the second word, and 1 copy of all the other words

To copy the field, you can do it manually - by creating the content yourself when you create the document, or you (maybe) can use some tweaking of the copyField feature. However, I'm unable to find a quick way to tweak it this way.

So, I'd say for now - copy it manually to another field.

Comment: I did it exactly as you described